# calling partial view as popup window on click of ajax actionlink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to open partial view as popup window which should contain image on click of ajax action link

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("View Document", "ViewDocument","Property",
                          new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", ViewBag.DocumentName } },
                new AjaxOptions{
                    HttpMethod="GET",
                    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
                    LoadingElementId="loading",
                    UpdateTargetId = "View"
                })
```

and by using that id i am finding filename and path of that image and returning partial view

```
public ActionResult ViewDocument(int id)
        {
                var document = db.Documents.Where(d => d.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                var documentFilename = document.FileName;
                ViewBag.Document = string.Format("~/App_Data/Uploads/{0}.jpg",documentFilename);
                return PartialView();
        }
```

and i my partial view looks like

```
@model MVC5Application.Models.Property

<img src="@ViewBag.Document" alt="" />
```

and am using jquery on click of ajax link

and jquery to popup partial view is

```
$(function () {
           $(document).dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               width: 1500,
               resizable: false,
               modal: true
           });
       });



       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#View Document').click(function () {
               $(document).load("@Url.Action("@ViewBag.Document")", function () {
                   $(document).dialog('open');
               });`enter code here`

               return false;
           });
       });
```

i dont know whether it is correct or not. i am new to mvc so please can any one solve the same.

advance thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you left out [HttpGet] on the controller method and use a break point on it to see if it is hit when the actionlink is clicked.